# Playa tag returning text string instead of entry ids

Tags: playa

I've just upgraded a site from EE 2.1 to EE 2.7.1 and got it basically working by upgrading the associated AddOns. Playa is still having trouble (migrated from 3.1 to the latest 4.4.5).

Simple Playa code that should return the entry_ids for the items selected within the `page_sidebar_content` field are instead returning a text string.

So,

```
 {page_sidebar_content backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/page_sidebar_content}
```

is returning something like:

```
 M140o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr
```

instead of something like

```
114|32|61
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Putting the code into an embed file works, but still not sure why that is necessary.

Comment: In what context are you using the Playa variable pair? This is definitely a parse order issue. If you update your question with more context surrounding the variable pair, it may be easier for someone to help suggest some changes to resolve the issue.

Comment: Any chance you're using Stash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that it was a conflict with the now deprecated [Twitter Timeline](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/twitter-timeline) Add-On. Once that old code was removed from the site, all worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

[Playa has an update script](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/installation.html) that you might have to trigger. Try **Add-Ons** → **Fieldtypes** → **Playa** to trigger Playa’s update script and see if that sorts things out.

Comment: Had tried that too and checked the database to make sure the correct fields are included ('parent_var_id' and 'parent_is_draft') and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [child_ids tag](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/field.html#child-ids-tag).

```
{page_sidebar_content:child_ids}
```

Comment: Already did. Same result.